# Do nomads in Banished wait?

Tags: banished

In Banished, if you have a batch of nomads asking entry and do not want to deny them per se, but just wait a little bit to stabilize your existing population, will they wait?

In other words, if you neither deny or accept, will they wait until you do one of those, no matter how long they are left waiting?

Answer (score 4):

No, Nomads will continue and go somewhere else if you don't respond within a few seasons.

Comment: that is, they WILL wait, but not forever.

Comment: Which is what I wrote. Hence the last part of my answer.

Comment: Just that starting that with "No" isn't the most clear way of putting it is all when they answer is actually "Yes, but"